# How to assign rooms most effeciently?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

## Story:

Our company will go outing soon. For our staying in the resort, every two of our colleagues will share one room. Our admin assistant has collected our preference of who to share rooms with, and now she has to decide how to arrange rooms to minimize the required number of room. Everyone will be arranged to share a room with somebody he or she would like to. For example, there are only colleagues, Allen would like to share a room with Bob or Chris, Bob would like to share with Chris, and Chris would like to share with Allen; then the only result will be: Allen and Chris share a room, and Bob uses a room alone, and in totall, 2 rooms are needed.

## Question:

To simplify the story as an algorithm question (which may not be the best simplification though): we have a few nodes in a graph, and the nodes connect to each other. We only care about nodes that are bi-directionally connected, so now we have an undirectional graph. How to divide the nodes in the undirectional graph into groups so that 1) any group contains at most 2 nodes, 2) if a group contains 2 nodes, the nodes are connected, 3) the number of the groups is minimized.

## Algorithm:

What comes over my head is to solve the question greedily. In every step of arrangement, just remove one isolated node or two nodes so that the number of edges remain in the graph is maximized. By doing so repeatedly, we will find a solution finally.

*Please either solve the question in an optimal way (and I am not looking for a way to try all combinations) or prove the greedy algorithm described above is optimal.*

Comment: The greedy algorithm is not optimal. Consider two 5-cycles joined by a single edge. There's no reason your algorithm won't remove one of the edges opposite a degree-3 vertex, which belongs to no maximum matching.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are solving is finding the [maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) in a graph. This means finding the maximum number of edges that do not share vertices. In your case, those edges would correspond to shared rooms, and the remaining vertices would be single rooms.

The maximum matching can be found using the [Blossom algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) in polynomial time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something crude in Haskell. The function, "pairs," lists all pairs with a mutual preference, and people without a mutual partner (paired with ""). The function, "choose," returns pairs from the pair list. If both people in a pair are also paired with another (same) third person, "choose" removes those two people from the rest of the pair list, as well as pairs emptied as a consequence. The number of rooms needed is equal to the length of the final list.

Output (it would be nice to have more varied examples to test):

```
*Main> choose graph
[["Chris","Allen"],["Bob","Isaak"]]

*Main> choose graph1
[["Allen","Chris"],["Bob",""],["Dave",""],["Chris","Max"]] --four rooms
  would be needed, although Chris appears in two pairs (..figured they can 
  decide later who stays where.)

*Main> choose graph2 --example given by Dante is not a Geek
[["Allen","Chris"],["Bob",""]]
```

Code:

```
import Data.List (group, sort, delete)

graph = [("Chris",["Isaak","Bob","Allen"]) --(person,preferences)
        ,("Allen",["Chris","Bob"])
        ,("Bob",["Allen","Chris","Isaak"])
        ,("Isaak",["Bob","Chris"])]

graph1 = [("Allen",["Bob","Chris"]), ("Bob",["Chris"]), ("Dave",[])
         ,("Chris",["Allen", "Max"]), ("Max", ["Chris"])]

graph2 = [("Allen",["Bob","Chris"]), ("Bob",["Chris"]), ("Chris",["Allen"])]

pairs graph = pairs' graph [] where
  pairs' []                 result = concat result
  pairs' (x@(person1,_):xs) result
    | null test = if elem [[person1, ""]] result 
                     then pairs' xs result
                     else pairs' xs ([[person1,""]]:result)
    | otherwise = 
        pairs' xs ((filter (\[x,y] -> notElem [y,x] (concat result)) test):result)
   where isMutual a b = elem (fst a) (snd b) && elem (fst b) (snd a)
         test = foldr comb [] graph
         comb a@(person2,_) b = 
           if isMutual a x then [person1,person2]:b else b

choose graph = comb paired [] where
  paired = pairs graph
  comb []             result = filter (/=["",""]) result
  comb (x@[p1,p2]:xs) result 
    | x == ["",""] = comb xs result
    | test         = 
        comb (map delete' xs) (x:map delete' result)
    | otherwise    = comb xs (x:result)
   where delete' [x,y] = if elem x [p1,p2] then ["",y]
                            else if elem y [p1,p2] then [x,""] 
                            else [x,y]
         test = if not . null . filter ((>=2) . length) . group 
                       . sort . map (delete p2 . delete p1) 
                       . filter (\y -> y /= x && (elem p1 y || elem p2 y)) $ paired
                   then True
                   else False
```

Comment: What makes you think that this will give an optimal answer?

Comment: @interjay Can you explain what you mean by optimal? Do you mean 'optimal' in terms of using the least time and computer-resources to obtain a correct answer? Or do you mean 'optimal' in terms of producing an optimal solution (i.e., the minimum number of needed rooms)?

Comment: I mean producing the best possible solution, i.e. minimum number of rooms.

Comment: @interjay oh, I'm not sure about that - to my understanding, it works for the examples I tried, and my idea seemed to make sense to me. But I would welcome more varied graphs to test and, if possible, learn from.